# REGEX '\K' is not working in RUTA but working in REGEX buidler

Tags: regex, uima, ruta, pega

I am trying to extract the last 3 characters from a pattern using below REGEX, which is working in online REGEX tester but not working in RUTA.

Below is the code that I have tried in online REGEX builder:
**https://regex101.com/r/2JN9a5/1**

Below is code that I have tried in RUTA:

```
"(?i)\\b([QI]{2}|[Q])[\\s || -]{0,2}[0-9]{5,}[\\s || -]{0,2}\\K[A-Z]{3}\\b" -> EntityType;
```

- Input  : `Q-123456-PAD`
- Exp O/p: `PAD`
- Input : `QI-1234567-PLB`
- Exp O/P: `PLB`

Comment: I guess ruta doesn't understand `\K` What is your question?

Comment: Well, I wanted to extract the last 3 characters from the above mentioned pattern. I tried doing so using '\K' but its not working in RUTA. So, just wanted to know how can I extract the last 3 characters without using '\K'

Comment: I don't know ruta syntax but I think you can make a group and select this group, something like `blah blah -]{0,2}([A-Z]{3})\\\b"` the value you want is in group 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is `Pega` then try this

```
PACKAGE uima.ruta.example;

DECLARE VarA;
DECLARE VarB;
DECLARE VarC;


W{REGEXP("Q|QI") -> MARK(VarA)}
 (WS|"-")?  
  NUM{REGEXP(".{1,7}")-> MARK(VarB)}
 (WS|"-")?
  W{REGEXP(".{1,3}")-> MARK(VarC),MARK(EntityType,5,5), UNMARK(VarA), UNMARK(VarB), UNMARK(VarC)};
```

Explanation:-

`(WS|"-")?` :-  Space or "-". You can remove the `?` if one of that is fixed.

`NUM{REGEXP(".{1,7}")` :- Number between 1 to 7.

`W{REGEXP(".{1,3}")` :- Capital alphabet 1 to 3.

`MARK(EntityType,5,5)` :- marking only the 5th row. i.e `W{REGEXP(".{1,3}")`. If you mark `MARK(EntityType,1,5)` then it will return `Q-123456-PAD`.

Comment: Wow..Thank u so much.. its working good...
I am trying to write similar logic for another pattern using RUTA script, but I couldn't get it.. Can u please help me in that?

I/P - AB-A1BCADE3-PAD (1st two alphanumeric, followed by '-' or space and followed by 7 alphanumeric chars and then followed by '-' or space with 3 Alphabets)
O/P - PAD

I couldn't get the exact output because of alphanumeric pattern.
It would be really helpful, thanks in advance.